# Vertically align checkboxes dynamically

Tags: html, css, forms, vertical-alignment

I have a form with four `checkboxes`, however it could happen that some `checkboxes` are hidden using `style="display: none"`. Which ones these are, is not known upfront. It could be `checkbox` 3 for example, or  `checkbox` 2 and 3.

However, this results in undesirable white space between the remaining boxes (as seen in the code example below).

How can I make sure remaining boxes are aligned nicely below each other; thus effectively removing big gaps of white space between them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" >
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>


  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" >
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>


  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" style="display: none">
  <label for="vehicle3" style="display: none"> I have a boat</label><br>


  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle4" name="vehicle4" value="Motor">
  <label for="vehicle4"> I have a motor</label><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Beginner with HTML/CSS, please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:

Add `style="display:none"` to the `br` tag as well:

```html
<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
  <br>


  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" style="display: none">
  <label for="vehicle3" style="display: none"> I have a boat</label>
  <br style="display:none">


  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle4" name="vehicle4" value="Motor">
  <label for="vehicle4"> I have a motor</label>
  <br>
  
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

#### Option 2:

Place each `input` and `br` tag inside the `label` tags, and remove`style="display:none"` from the `input` tag. 
Added bonus: with this method, you can also remove the `for` and `id` attributes.

```html
<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" >
      I have a bike<br>
  </label>

  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
      I have a car<br>
  </label>

  <label style="display: none"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
      I have a boat<br>
  </label>

  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle4" value="Motor">
      I have a motor<br>
  </label>
  
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Option 2 is definitely the better route unless there's some requirement that the items not be grouped inside a containing element.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you hide your input and label hide a br tag as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
 <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" >
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" >
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" style="display: none">
<label for="vehicle3" style="display: none"> I have a boat</label><br style="display: none">
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle4" name="vehicle4" value="Motor">
<label for="vehicle4"> I have a motor</label><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```